# Edit DIVs after .append()

Tags: php, jquery, css, append

My algorithm:

1. I get the DIV text from php/SQL (`$.get( "read.php"...`)
2. `APPEND` contenteditable div with loaded text by jQuery
3. check the `div` value, if there is errors in text I make `div` red (assign class, `$(this).addClass("fill_red");`)
4. on every change of text - check and assign/remove class if needed.

**Problem is:** with preloaded text - everything is working.
But when I append div using JS - check function don't works. 
I searched the web, maybe `on()` method helps me.

But what event?

It should be something like `onload`, `onchange`..?

*(yes, I could make `div` generated by php and solve the problem, but I dont want full refresh)*

Thank you!

part of code:

`//texts load
    $(function() {
    $.get( "read.php", function( data ) {
      var ionka = data.split(' ');
      ionka.forEach(function(item, i, arr) {
        var app_text = "<div id=\"segm" + i + "\" contenteditable                 role=\"textbox\">" + item + "</div>";
        $("#textarea").append(app_text);
      });
    }); 
    //checks
    var intRegex = new RegExp('^[0-9/\]{5}$'); 
    $('#textarea div').each(function(i,elem) {
      if(!intRegex.test($(this).text())) {
        $(this).addClass("fill_red");
      }else{
        $(this).removeClass();
      }
    });
    // edit on change. Blur because of contenteditable 
    var segm_array = [];
    $('#textarea div').each(function(i,elem) {
    $(this).blur(function() {
    if (segm_array[i]!=$(this).text()){
        segm_array[i] = $(this).text();
           if(!intRegex.test(segm_array[i])) {
              $(this).addClass("fill_red");
           }else{
              $(this).removeClass();

           }
    }
    });
    });`

Comment: so where is your code?

Comment: Hm, its big + works only for pre-generated page.

Comment: hmmm.... I am not mentalist ... probably you'll find one here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You dont show much code here, but my guess is that you are trying to add class before new data is loaded into dom

```
$.get( "read.php" ).done(function( data ) {
    // addClass etc
});
```

Comment: Thx! I'll try it now. But I also need to add class on every edit.